# Error when installing AWS Connector on VMWare vCenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, vsphere

I have downloaded the AWS Connector OVF file from AWS https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-connector/AWS-Connector.ova and I am trying to deploy via vSphere desktop client by going to File->Deploy  OVA Template. But I am getting error

[image: Error that appears after I have selected thin provision]

Any idea what could be the source of this error?

Windows version is 8.1 and vSphere client version is 5.5.0 and same is the version of vCenter Server.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this post one year ago, I'm not sure is still valid with new vSphere version.
http://www.dbigcloud.com/cloud-computing/211-como-conectar-nuestro-vmware-vcenter-server-a-aws.html

Comment: Where is the link for **AWS Connector for vCenter**?

Comment: No I am talking about this particular image in your tutorial http://www.dbigcloud.com/images/articulos/aws_vcenter/00-AWS_connector.PNG

Comment: the OVF template deployed has the IP for that URL.